# Java - Seven-segment-display a number

Tags: java

I have written this code:

```
public class bsp {
    static void row1(int ergebnis) {

        switch (ergebnis % 10) {

            case 1:
                Out.println("");
                break;

            case 2:
                Out.println(" __");
                break;

            case 3:
                Out.println(" __");
                break;

            case 4:
                Out.println("");
                break;

            case 5:
                Out.println(" __");
                break;

            case 6:
                Out.println(" __");
                break;

            case 7:
                Out.println("__");
                break;

            case 8:
                Out.println(" __ ");
                break;

            case 9:
                Out.println(" __ ");
                break;

            case 0:
                Out.println(" __ ");
                break;

        }
    }

    static void row2(int ergebnis) {

        switch (ergebnis % 10) {

            case 1:
                Out.println("|");
                break;

            case 2:
                Out.println("   |");
                break;

            case 3:
                Out.println("   |");
                break;

            case 4:
                Out.println("|  |");
                break;

            case 5:
                Out.println("|");
                break;

            case 6:
                Out.println("|");
                break;

            case 7:
                Out.println("  |");
                break;

            case 8:
                Out.println("|  |");
                break;

            case 9:
                Out.println("|  |");
                break;

            case 0:
                Out.println("|  |");
                break;
        }
    }

    static void row3(int ergebnis) {

        switch (ergebnis % 10) {

            case 1:
                Out.println("|");
                break;

            case 2:
                Out.println(" __|");
                break;

            case 3:
                Out.println(" __|");
                break;

            case 4:
                Out.println("|__|");
                break;

            case 5:
                Out.println("|__");
                break;

            case 6:
                Out.println("|__");
                break;

            case 7:
                Out.println("  |");
                break;

            case 8:
                Out.println("|__|");
                break;

            case 9:
                Out.println("|__|");
                break;

            case 0:
                Out.println("|  |");
                break;
        }
    }

    static void row4(int ergebnis) {

        switch (ergebnis % 10) {

            case 1:
                Out.println("|");
                break;

            case 2:
                Out.println("|");
                break;

            case 3:
                Out.println("   |");
                break;

            case 4:
                Out.println("   |");
                break;

            case 5:
                Out.println("   |");
                break;

            case 6:
                Out.println("|  |");
                break;

            case 7:
                Out.println("  |");
                break;

            case 8:
                Out.println("|  |");
                break;

            case 9:
                Out.println("   |");
                break;

            case 0:
                Out.println("|  |");
                break;
        }
    }

    static void row5(int ergebnis) {

        switch (ergebnis % 10) {

            case 1:
                Out.println("|");
                break;

            case 2:
                Out.println("|__");
                break;

            case 3:
                Out.println(" __|");
                break;

            case 4:
                Out.println("   |");
                break;

            case 5:
                Out.println(" __|");
                break;

            case 6:
                Out.println("|__|");
                break;

            case 7:
                Out.println("  |");
                break;

            case 8:
                Out.println("|__|");
                break;

            case 9:
                Out.println(" __|");
                break;

            case 0:
                Out.println("|__|");
                break;

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ergebnis = 2;
        row1(ergebnis);
        row2(ergebnis);
        row3(ergebnis);
        row4(ergebnis);
        row5(ergebnis);
    }
}
```

My goal is to enter a number into the variable "Ergebnis" that gets printed out in a seven segment display (as seen in the picture attached)
My code works with single digits but i dont know how to make it work with multiple digits.. can someone help?

Comment: Please, do not post link to your code (links tend to rot and die). Instead post the [relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question and format it with the `{ }` button in the editor.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What's `Out`? You mean `System.out`?

Comment: Put the various strings in an array of String, then each of your methods becomes a single line "System.out.println(myStrings[ergebnis%10])"

Comment: You mean to print them in the same "row" or can be in different rows?

Comment: Also consider that you have extra characters. So instead of having a 7-segment display, you actually have a "14-segment display" (print 8 and count the "|" and "_")